# Brachot with no shirt on

Tags: halacha, blessing, clothing, netilat-yadayim-washing, shacharis-morning-prayer

Can a man say a bracha when not wearing a shirt? In the morning, for example, before getting fully dressed, one might wash his hands, put on pants and a kippa, say 'al netilat yadayim,' 'asher yatzar,' 'elokai netzor,' and 'al mitzvat tzitzit,' and then don the tzitzit and finish getting dressed. Is this correct?

Comment: So your question is about saying Berachoth with no shirt on, not about "Morning Brachot" as in your title, correct?

Comment: @SethJ essentially yes, but particularly when people normally say these 4 brachot in the morning